# Power Automate: When item is modified in list A, Copy ID column values to list B

Tags: power-automate, powerapp

I am trying to do the following:
When ID in Col A is modified or created in SP list A, Copy that value to List B Col B.

Is this possible to do?

Here is what Im trying:

[image]

Comment: After new item created or existing item modified in list A, you should just ads/update only that particular item in list B. You don't need to get all items from list A and then update in list B.

Comment: @GaneshSanap would you be able to show screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]

it's simple :

1. When an Item is created or modified in List A,
2. Update Item in List B (where they get match with the same ID), the ID passed in this action is the ID of the modified item from List A (from previous step).

Comment: You don't have to get all list items while you already have in your context the modified item

Comment: Hey - it didnt seem to work. I want to create a copy of the Request_ID from list A to list B when an item is modified or created in List A.  So I only have the two windows now. 1) When an item is created or modified (test passes this step), and 2) Update Item,  with my  list B, List b Name and ID = ID. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- No need to query SPO list again after creation or modification in order to create it or copy it in another list.
- You will get all list item detail from "Item created or modified trigger'
- refer this screen shot.
  [image: when item is created and modified]
- You can skip ***Get Item*** action in this case and directly use create list item action.
- Refer below screen shot, how I have created the flow for copying the list item in another list.

[image: Copy List item to another list]

- Here I am copying list item from EmployeeProfile list to ProfileDetails list.

Comment: thank you, however wont this create duplicate values each time it is run? –

Comment: in that case create lookup column in destination list and update based on lookup id

Comment: would you be able to provide screenshots?